# Date based Query MongoDB Collection

Tags: performance, mongodb

We have huge MongoDB with 70 Million records as of today. every day almost 1 Million records will be inserted in to this database. each document in the collection will have following data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5447f506e4b081e36588b006"),    
    "time" : "2014-10-22T15:16:32.000Z", 
    "created" : "2014-10-22T15:24:39.847Z", 
    "type" : "system",
    "upload" : "2"
}
```

every day we have to run some jobs to process the data daily basis. when we run the jobs, we will save the last documents details in our status log. When we the job next time, we will have to get the created time from this record, extract all the documents after this date from the MongoDB. i got struck in writing query for extracting the documents which are not processed i.e. fetch the records after the date saved in log. Can somebody help to write the MongoDB query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a variable called `$date`:

```
db.collection.find({created: {"$gt": $date}})
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/

Comment: as a side note, since [ObjectIds are made from timestamps](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), you could remove the `created` field altogether, and operate directly on `_id`

Comment: db.collection.find({'created': {'$lt': '2014-10-22T15:17:02.000Z'}}).. I have tried this.. but not returning any results.

Comment: i have tried using _id. It's working and it's super fast when compared to created field queries.. Thanks Sean

Comment: It's faster because `_id` is indexed by default. You would do as well with an indexed `created` field stored as a date type (not a string). I'd suggest doing this, since it will be easier to work with an explicit created field of date type, especially if you are going to display the created time or you need to insert a document with a created time different from the time when its inserted.

Comment: i agree with @wdberkeley if (and only if) you need to distinguish between record creation time and record insertion time. But i absolutely agree that performance increase you are seeing is because the field is indexed.  Use [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) and [ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) on your queries to keep things optimal. Your goal is to avoid table scans and shoot for covered queries.